# How to include the zip generated by LWJGL configurator in Gradle

Tags: gradle, lwjgl

I downloaded a zip file using the LWJGL configurator [here](https://www.lwjgl.org/customize)
How do I include this in a `build.gradle` file?  I am thinking it would go under dependencies.

Also, the [install guide](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Install#gradle-or-maven) mentions just using the buildscript instead of the zip.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't choose the zip mode, but the "Gradle" or "Maven" mode (under "Mode") when you use Gradle/Maven.
So, go to https://www.lwjgl.org/customize and then under "Mode" choose "Gradle". This will produce a portion of the build.gradle file containing the dependency declarations for the modules you chose.

EDIT (see comment below): This however only works for the "Release" and "Nightly" versions of LWJGL3, and not for the "Stable" version because "Stable" references a particular snapshot build which is impossible to reference with maven/gradle artifact coordinates.

Comment: You need to use the nightly version to get those options.